# Como hago que cada los botones de las cards, hagan aprecer la descripcion de la misma

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach, card

estoy haciendo unas cartas, especificamente 3, pero aqui les mostrare el codigo como si fuesen 2, para no subir tanto codigo, en las que se presentan mis proyectos de mi portafolio. El problema es que cada una de esas cartas tiene un botón, el cual al presionarlo necesito que muestre la descripción de cada uno de esos proyectos. El botón de la primera carta funciona (lo presiono y aparece la descripcion correspondiente a esa carta), pero si presiono el otro boton de la otra carta, no aparece su descripcion correspondiente. Por si no se entendio, el objetivo es que al presionar el boton de descripcion, aparezca la descripcion correspondiente a esa carta, de alguna manera necesito que el boton sepa identificar que boton de que carta fue presionado y mostrar esa carta. Yo creo que tengo un problema en el Javascript, pero no encuentro la solución, espero haber sido clara y sino consultenme.

```js
const btnDescription = document.querySelector('#btn-description'); 
const cardBody = document.getElementsByClassName("card-body");
const btnClose = document.getElementById('btn-close'); 
const fullImg = document.querySelector(".full-img");

document.querySelectorAll("#btn-description").forEach(cardBody => {
    btnDescription.addEventListener('click', () => {
        fullImg.style.display = "flex";
    });
});
```

```css
.cards {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border: 2px solid #696969;
    box-shadow: 0px 17px 15px rgba(18, 18, 18, .6);
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-body button {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.cards-info {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.full-img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-img" id="full-img">
      <div class="cards-info">
         <h2>Titulo</h2>
          <br>
         <p>
           Lorem alskdjlwekmdpwelkd
         </p> 
      </div>
      <span id="btn-close">X</span>
    </div>
       <div class="cards">
          <h3>titulo</h3>
          <!--img-->
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="links">
            <!--links-->
            </div>
          <button id="btn-description">Descripción</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="full-img" id="full-img">
      <div class="cards-info">
         <h2>Titulo 2</h2>
          <br>
         <p>
           Lorem alskdjlwekmdpwelkd
         </p> 
      </div>
      <span id="btn-close">X</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
        <h3>titulo 2</h3>
        <!--img-->
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="links">
          <!--links-->
          </div>
          <button id="btn-description">Descripción</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Los IDs en el DOM **deben ser únicos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)...

Comment: @padaleiana cambie los id por clases para no repetirlos, pero sigue sin funcionar, alguna solucion?

Comment: No olvides actualizar tu snippet para ver qué cambios efectuaste.

Answer (score -1):

Como primera observación, no puedes tener varios elementos con el mismo id en un documento, aunque funciona, sintácticamente está mal y en algún momento te va a generar un problema, cámbialos por clases.

El problema es que en tu `.forEach()` la función que estas pasando tiene un `eventlistener` sobre `btnDescription` el cual hace referencia a `#btn-description` y en cada iteración vuelve a lanzar un evento sobre ese mismo elemento que será siempre el primero que encuentra en todo el documento.

Solución: el parámetro que estas pasando en esa función del `.forEach()` osea `cardBody` contiene el elemento sobre el cual debes lanzar el `eventlistener`  usalo con él, no con `btnDescription`.

```js
 cardBody.addEventListener('click', () => {
   // Lo que sea que pase en el evento
 }
```

Además en `fullImg` te sucederá lo mismo, estarás aplicando *flex* al primer nodo que se encuentre en el documento ya que usaste `querySelector`, tendrás que usar `querySelectorAll` para recuperar todos los nodos de `.full-img` e iterar por cada uno.

```js
const fullImg = document.querySelectorAll(".full-img");
```

Para iterar en cada `fullImg` en tu función  `cardBody => {}` tienes que pasar un segundo parámetro que contiene el índice.

Nota que ahora tendrás que poner los argumentos dentro de paréntesis ya que las funciones de flecha lo requieren cuando hay 2 o más argumentos.

```js
 (cardBody, index) => {
   // event listener
 }
```

Y ahora pasas ese índice para iterar en cada `fullImg`, esto es asumiendo que los indices de cada `#btn-description` (que ya comentamos que deberías cambiarlo a una clase) coinciden con los índices de cada `.full-img`

```js
fullImg[index].style.display = "flex";
```

Para tener mayor control sobre que descripción pertenece a que tarjeta sería mejor hacer un contenedor padre y meter ahí tanto botón como descripción ó si no tienes muchas tarjetas usa ids numerados `#card-1 #full-img1 #card-2 #full-img2`

**Procura tener mejor redacción, no te comas palabras, usa puntos, comas, saltos de líneas para que tus preguntas sean más claras. Facilítale la vida a quienes te ayudan aquí.**

Comment: Muchas gracias @AHrtzt, lo vi tarde, en parte lo había resuelto pero me faltaba una cosa y con tu ayuda lo logre, te agradezco y gracias por tu tiempo